# Two SVN Repository Perspectives in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

For Android development I'm using Eclipse Indigo and Subclipse 1.6.18.

I happened to notice today that when I go to Window > Open Perspective I see **two** SVN Repository Perspectives.  One says "SVN Repository Exploring" and the other says the same thing but inside angle brackets, i.e,

```
"<SVN Repository Exploring>".
```

The first one brings up a blank window; the angle-bracket one brings up a window with my repositories in an upper tab and "task repositories" in a lower tab.

I also noticed that if I go to Help > Install New Software and show what's already installed,and uninstall all the Subclipse components, and restart Eclipse, these two SVN perspectives still exist.   They don't work anymore because of missing SVN components but they're still there.

So where do these two SVN repository perspectives come from and why one with, and one without, angle-brackets?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try starting Eclipse with the -clean parameter on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two if you have both Subclipse and Subversive installed.  However, note that your workspace also will save and remember perspectives, particularly if you customize and save them.  Try starting Eclipse with a new workspace and see if they go away.

Comment: Both of the above answers (Mark and Gilbert) propose ways to get rid of them.  But I never said I was trying to get rid of them.   My question is What are they, why do I see two of them and what's the significance of the angle-brackets?    The only subversion clients I have are Subclipse and the 64 bit version of Tortoise SVN (my Eclipse is the 32 bit version)

Comment: You should only have one.  I am saying it is something specific to your workspace and a new workspace will probably resolve it.